# how to mock ProcessInstance and return back mocked Object in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

How to mock ProcessInstance and return the Object.

```
variables.put("testId", id);
variables.put("setDays", 1);
RuntimeService runtime = delegate.getProcessEngineServices().getRuntimeService();
ProcessInstance instance = runtime.startProcessInstanceByKey("schedule_day", businessKey,variables);
String paymentId = instance.getProcessInstanceId();
```

**Here I mocked RuntimeService,ProcessInstance**

runtime.startProcessInstanceByKey("schedule_day", businessKey, variables);
when ever I am mocking above line getting ambiguous method call. It is only allowing

```
Mockito.when(runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(String.class)));
```

but my case

```
Mockito.when(runtimeService.startProcessInstanceById(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(String.class),Mockito.any(Map.class)));
```

Comment: What is the difference between two mocking pieces of code you've posted? They look exactly the same to me.

Comment: both are different .In last parameter above one we used String.class and below one is Map.class

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Mockito but you could try to use `Mockito.anyMap()` instead of `Mockito.any(Map.class)`, maybe that will work for you.

Comment: `startProcessInstanceByKey` in code vs `startProcessInstanceById` in test